# Repated Cartesian product in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to have a Cartesian product, say, from {0,1} x {0,1} x ... x {0,1} (n times). The result should be like :

**{(0,0,...,0),(0,0,...,1),....,(1,1,...,1)}**.

Before asking a question, I've tried many ways with array, list, arraylist and found some libraries which don't fully meet my expectations. So could some one help me out there?

The starting array looks like this:

```
    int[] index_old_x = new int[m];
    for (int i=0; i < m; i++) {
        index_old_x[i] = i;
    }
```

How can I implement a method to do a n-times Cartesian product on it? Of course, each set can have more than 2 items. But it is important that all sets are of the same length.

Comment: Will you always have only two items per set? If not, will all your sets always be the same size?

Comment: @jimboweb nope, two items per set are only given as example. Of course each set can have more than 2 items, but always of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I implement a method to do a n-times Cartesian product on it?

Here's a conventional implementation which dimensions the array array with the proper sizes at the start and builds the product stepwise, replicating the results from the previous steps.

```
        int cp[][] = new int[(int)Math.pow(m, n)][n], l = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        {
            int o = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < l; ++j)
                {
                    cp[o][n-1-k] = index_old_x[i];
                    System.arraycopy(cp[j], n-k, cp[o], n-k, k);
                    ++o;
                }
            l = o;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cp));
```